# Goy Versus Leum

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, words, hebrew, parashat-toldot

The Posuk Says (Gen. 25,23):

> שְׁנֵי [גיים] גוֹיִם בְּבִטְנֵךְ וּשְׁנֵי לְאֻמִּים מִמֵּעַיִךְ יִפָּרֵדוּ

Translated as: Two nations are in your womb, and two kingdoms will separate from your innards

What is the diffrence between a גוֹיִם and a לְאֻמִּים

Comment: can you clarify your question. As you translated, one means nations and one means kingdoms.

Comment: Unless otherwise specified I am using the Metusdah translation I want to know what the practical difference in the Hebrew  the English is Lav Davka Precise

Comment: @simchashatorah per the example set by Esther, please give credit *in each question* to the source of any words that you got from somewhere else, including translations. The easy (and useful to others) way is to link to the translation you're using (e.g. chabad.org). Don't rely on statements like "unless otherwise specified," because 90% of the people who read anything you write here are reading only that piece and have no idea about anything else on this site, including your comments elsewhere.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22967

Answer (score 7):

Although Rashi (to [Tehilim 2:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39989&st=&pgnum=11)) quotes Menachem (ben Sruk) who says that the two terms are essentially similar, [Netziv](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14024&st=&pgnum=193) and [Malbim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40102&st=&pgnum=240) both say basically the same thing (which Malbim repeats to Tehilim [2:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39989&st=&pgnum=11) and [117:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39989&st=&pgnum=366)): A "גוי" is a bunch of people who get together, while a "לאום" is a nation with a unique identity and culture. [HaKsav VeHaKabbalah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14121&st=&pgnum=124), in a slightly different comment, says that a "לאום" is a people united under a king. [Rabbi Hirsch](http://archive.org/stream/amishahumshetora01hirsuoft#page/n241/mode/2up) defines a "לאום" as a form of government.

Answer (score 2):

From the context,  it is obvious that not every goy becomes an am.

What I imagine the difference is, is that an Am is a group of people with a deep sense of togetherness, as if they all came from the same mother.

A Goy, is a nation, which is a political faction joined together by their ideas and political philosphy.  An Am that has a civil war, will become two Goyim.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be borne out by Rashi to Gen. 14:1, where he explains that "Tidal king of Goyim" was king of "a place named Goyim, because members of various nations and places gathered together there, and appointed a king over themselves." So there was a single "le'om" (as Rashi here explains, "a kingdom") formed out of many Goyim.

Comment: avi, are you saying _l'om_ and _am_ are the same?