# Why switch the reference from "גוי" to "עם" in Tachanun?

Tags: words, prayer-book, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, tachanun

Why does the prayer "Shomer Yisra'el" in Tachanun say in two of the verses the word גוי in the first and last phrase, but עם in the middle phrase?

> שומר גוי אחד שמור שארית עם אחד ואל יאבד גוי אחד

...

> שומר גוי קדוש שומר שארית עם קדוש ואל יאבד גוי קדוש

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11482

Answer (score 1):

What I am writing is an idea that is recorded by the Malbim on chapter 1 verse 4 of Sefer Yeshayau.. [(you can see it here in Hebrew)](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%99%22%D7%9D_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%90_%D7%93)  any errrors are the translator's (mine).
He seems to say that the difference between "Goy" and "Am" is that **"Goy"**: refers to a people who share (some of these things not necessarily all these things) ancestry, language, family, and possibly locale. **"Am"**:refers to a group of people united under a leader, government or unified philosophy and act as a whole entity rather than the individual.  I will try and llok into it more...

Comment: The question remains why each word was chosen for its respective part of the prayer.

Comment: In English, that means goy = nation vs. am = state... sorta.  Neat!

Comment: Also, is it then the "שארית" that makes the distinction?  That though it's the full nation, it's the remainder of the state.  Then the question of why remains but this helps get there.

Answer (score 0):

I assume its a girsa thing because it happens during havdoloh too. I Daven nosach baladi-teimani/ RaMbaM. For Shabboth we say joyim not amim, same with havdoloh. I asks by rov who davens chassidishe nosach Sefard, and he said that the gemoroh in ( I forgot) mentions the text and he said it says amim not goyim. So the kasha in on RaMbaM. I truly believe its a girsa thing. Maybe someone who has the vilna edition of RaMbaM can check what the text is compared to the Mori kafih/frankel Misheh Toroh since the vilna edition usually changed the text according to it's own girsa instead of what RaMbaM wrote.

Comment: You must know that your Frankel Rambam set has a listing of the various Nuschaot in the different manuscripts/editions. Why not check there instead of asking someone else to?

Comment: Because I don't use frankel I use kafih and magbili.

Comment: Don't you mean a Jirsa? And Mishne Thoroh?

Comment: I don't think it's a Thow/Sov,but a regular Tow. Next time I comment on a post with ivrith, I'll transliterate my way to make you happy. But be warned there might be a flood of comments saying stop or I can't understand you.

Comment: http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/3129n.htm halochoh jimmal: הַמַּבְדִּיל בֵּין קֹדֶשׁ לַחֹל, וּבֵין אוֹר לַחֹשֶׁךְ, וּבֵין יִשְׂרָאֵל לַגּוֹיִים, וּבֵין יוֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִי לְשֵׁשֶׁת יְמֵי הַמַּעֲשֶׂה.  בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ה', הַמַּבְדִּיל בֵּין קֹדֶשׁ לַחֹל.

Comment: joyeem lo 3meem. http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14278&st=&pgnum=127 this has 3meem.

Comment: I also want to add that nosa7 baladi doesn't say shomer yisroayl, we say ovinu malkeinu followed by regular wa'ana7nu lo ned3. I don't know who these guys are but they seem to have joyeem as well http://www.hibba.org/node/423. I checked chabads siddur online and they have it your way. Many words in nosa7 chabad were changed according to the baal hatanya which are not in the regular chassidishe nosa7 sefard. Not to mention their nosa7 sefard is not the same nosa7 sefaradim have. Like I said it is all a jeersa thing and I wouldn't be so worried lest you are really into jeersoth like me.