# Nation, people, kingdom?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, commentaries, dictionary

What definitions fit the most with these words:

לאם/לאום (l'om)
עם (am)
גוי (goy)
ממלכה (mamlachah)

They are all refering to Israel and the other people in the world; but how do i understand them when used in biblical references?

Examples of possible answers I was thinking of:

- unified body of individuals; a group of people bound together
- a community of people who share a common language, culture, ethnicity, descent, or history, etc.
- an organized community living under a unified political system, the government
- kingdom (A kingdom is a territory or group of people ruled by the same monarch)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11482 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22967

Answer (score 2):

Here is something from ברק השחר (Collection of explanations of this sort from the Gra, with additions)

[image: barack haShachar pages]

Comment: I said it was from ברק השחר, the page number in the edition can be seen on the image. If you think it's better than nothing I'll delete it, but as there was no other answer (and there still isn't) I think it is helpful. The image is perfectly readable to me, perhaps opening it in a new tab will be helpful (right click or long press the image for the option)

Comment: I do not know of a clickable resource, which is why I took the time to take and upload this image, and I have no intention of transcribing the 2 pages. I went now and the version on hebrewbooks and it only provides references to the Gra's comments quoted in full above, and nothing of the additional sources in fineprint. I am still reasonably new here, and I accept that translating a paragraph or 2 has enough utility that it could be asked of answers to take the time to translate, but this seems a bit much
(Apologies if I'm coming off as aggressive here, I get that you're following guidelines)

Comment: I think it would be "the morning('s) light" but I think it would make more sense to just transliterate "barack haShachar" for the book's name

Answer (score 2):

The Malbim in the beginning of [Yishiah (1:4)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.1.4?lang=he&with=Malbim%20Beur%20Hamilot&lang2=he) explains the terms גוי and עם at length:

> גוי, עם. ההבדל ביניהם, גוי יקרא מצד הקיבוץ לבד, כי גוי מענין קיבוץ וזה יהיה ע''פ ארבעה דברים, א) שיתקבצו מצד הארץ והמדינה שיושבים בה, ב) מצד שפתם שמדברים בה. ג) מצד משפחתם שיצאו ממנה, ד) מצד הסכמתם וקבוצם להיות גוי אחד עפ''י נמוסים שחקקו להם לאחד הקיבוץ שלהם, כמ''ש (בראשית י' ה') מאלה נפרדו איי הגוים, א) בארצותם, ב) איש ללשונו, ג) למשפחותם, ד) בגוייהם, פי' בקבוציהם, והוכפל שם (לא). אבל בשם עם יקרא מצד הממשלה אשר עליהם אשר תשימם לגוי אחד ותנהיג אותם כנפש המנהגת את הגויה, ומצד זה יבוא שם עם בכינוי הקנין, עמי. עמו, עמך, עם ה', לא כן שם גוי כי התיחסות הקיבוץ אל אדוניהם יהיה מצד הממשלה, לא מצד הקיבוץ. ומה שנמצאו ויתר גויי ינחלום (צפניה ב' ט'), לשמוח בשמחת גויך (תהלות קו ה') זה יצדק אצל ה' לבד, כי לו יתיחס צירוף הקנין גם בגוף יצוריו בעצמם בזולת השקף על קשר המלוכה, לפ''ז מבואר כי בכ''מ שם עם מציין מדרגה גדולה יותר משם גוי, יען שזה מורה על שהם מונהגים מאיזה מטרה, וזה מורה רק הקיבוץ לבד, וכן הגבילם. ויתהלכו מגוי אל גוי ומממלכה אל עם אחר (דה''א טז כ'. תהלות קה יג). ואמר ואני אקניאם בלא עם (רק) בגוי נבל אכעיסם, מבואר שיש גוי שאינו עם. ואמר ההימיר גוי אלהים וגו' ועמי המיר כבודו (ירמיה ב' יא). עיניו בגוים תצפינה הסוררים אל ירומו למו סלה (אבל), ברכו עמים אלהינו וזמ''ש ונתתיך לבז בגוים והכרתיך מן העמים (יחזקאל כה ז'), ר''ל עמים החשובים יכריתו אותך מארצם לגמרי, וגם הגוים הפחותים אשר שם תמצא בית תהיה לבז בתוכם, וע''כ ציין ברוב המקומות שם עם לישראל עם קרובו, ושם גוי, לגוים עובדי אלילים, לבד בעת שירצה לדבר מן הריבוי היותו גוי גדול, אז ישמש בשם גוי, כי שם גוי כולל קיבוץ גדול, ושם עם יבא על פרט וחלק מן הקיבוץ וגם על משפחה מיוחדת, עם הארץ ירגמוהו באבן (ויקרא כ' ב'), כיון על העומדים במעמד שם, ואם היה אומר גוי, היה הכונה על כל האומה, ומצאנוהו גם על שלשה אנשים, אמנם כי אתם עם (איוב יב ב'), וע''כ אמר, וראה כי עמך הגוי הזה (שמות לג ג'), עמך הוא שם הכבוד וגוי שם הריבוי. וכן רק עם חכם ונבון הגוי הגדול הזה (דברים ד' ו'). ואמר כן העם הזה וכן הגוי הזה לפני (חגי ב' יד), ר''ל בין העם הזה הכהנים המצויינים בהדרת קדש, וכן הגוי בכלל חללו קדושתם, ועיין לקמן ב' ג' וד'. ט' ב'. י' ו'. י''א י'. י''ד ו'. י''ח ב' וז'. כ''ה ג'. ל' כ''ח. מ''ב ו'. מ''ט כ''ב. ם''א ט'. ם''ה א' וב'), ומש''ש :

Latter [(17:12)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.17.12?lang=he&with=Malbim%20Beur%20Hamilot&lang2=he) he explains the term לאום:

> עמים, לאמים. הבדלם בארתי במק''א באורך, עמים מורה על קבוצים שיש להם ממשלה (כי זה המבדיל בין עם לגוי שגוי מורה הקיבוץ לבד כנ''ל א' ד'), ולאום מורה על אומה המתאחדת מצד שיש לה דת מיוחדת, ואיזה אמונה אשר תצרפם, לא מצד הממשלה שיש להם מלך אחד רק מצד האמונה שיש להם אמונה אחת, וכן מצאתי ברבה בראשית (פרשה סג) ולאום מלאום יאמץ, ר' חלבו אמר עד כאן קריין סבתא ורעמה וסבתכא, מכאן ואלך יהודין וארמאין עכ''ל, ר''ל שיהיה שינוי דת ביניהם, וע''ל (לד א'), ובזה לאומים כולל יותר מעמים, כי עמים רבים וממלכות שונות יתקבצו תחת דת אחת :

And elsewhere [(9:3)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.9.6?lang=he&with=Malbim%20Beur%20Hamilot&lang2=he) he explains the difference between ממלכה and מלכות:

> ממלכתו. יש הבדל בין ממלכה ובין מלוכה נושא השם ההגיוני של מלוכה הוא המלך, ונושא השם ההגיוני של ממלכה הוא העם והמדינה, ובררתי זה במקום אחר :

According to this, I would translate גוי as 'ethnicity', עם as 'nation', לאום as 'religious group', and ממלכה as 'kingdom' in respect to the nation-state rather than the king.